# What is the purpose of && :; in bash scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've come across a bash script which runs the following command within a function

```
set -e
rm -rf some_dir/* && :;
```

What is the purpose of `&& :;` in this context?

**Edit:**

I understand that it's synonym to `&& true`, but now I don't undertand why it bypass `set -e`

Trying it out I see that running the following

```
#!/bin/bash -e

# false
echo false alone return 1 and fail with -e

false || true
echo "false || true return $?"

false || :;
echo "false || :; return $?"

false && true
echo "false && true return $?"

false && :;
echo "false && :; return $?"

false && :
echo "false && : return $?"
```

Outputs

```
false alone return 1 and fail with -e
false || true return 0
false || :; return 0
false && true return 1
false && :; return 1
false && : return 1
```

Comment: Is there a `set -e` statement earlier in the script?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Yes there is

Comment: `rm || :` has the effect of ensuring that the command is successful. `rm && :` does not change the exit status of the list, but does have the side effect of changing the behavior of `errexit`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it suppresses the effect of `set -e` can be found in the man page:

```
-e      Exit immediately if a simple command (see SHELL GRAMMAR above) exits with a non-zero status.
        The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the  command  list  immediately
        following  a while or until keyword, part of the test in an if statement, part of a && or ||
        list, or if the command's return value is being inverted via !.  A trap on ERR, if  set,  is
        executed before the shell exits.
```

For emphasis: `The shell does not exit if the command that fails is ... part of a && or || list`

Note that there is some subtlety here.  A common error is to write code like `foo() { ...; rm path; #cleanup }`  in which the intent is to always be successful.  By which I mean that the author of the code didn't really even think about the exit status of `foo` but implicitly expects is to succeed and doesn't care about the exit status of `rm`, forgetting that `foo` returns the exit status of `rm`.  The code might be re-written `rm path || :` to ensure that `foo` always returns successfully, or `rm path && :`  to return the status of `rm` but not exit if `errexit` is enabled.  Frankly, it's too subtle and I believe one additional reason for never using `set -e`.   Also, an argument could be made that you should never rely on the exit status of code unless you explicitly `exit` a script or `return` from a function.

Answer (score 0):

The `&&` is easy to explain. From the bash `man` page:

```
command1 && command2
```

> command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status of zero.

`:` is harder to find in the docs. `:` is a builtin that is equivalent to `true`:

```
:; echo $? 
0
```

So overall, this command equates to:

> Recursively remove the directory, and if the rm is successful, run 'true'.

It's seems unnecessary though, since `&&` has already 'tested' that rm is returning true, so it's a bit like doing `true && true`.

More commonly this is used when you want an `if/else` where only the `else` does something, e.g.

```
if command1; then :; else command2; fi
```

Though this is only useful if your system doesn't have a `true` command, which is arguably easier for a later reader of the code to understand. (Or you could use a negative test and not bother with a no-op at all).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the `:` equivalent to `true`. I can see why someone would use `|| :;` but still don't understand when `&& :;` is useful

Comment: For 1'000'000 iterations `&& :` is slightly faster than `&& true` :)
(tested on Bash v4.4.23)